# How to scrape youtube comments and their posting date

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm **scraping** youtube videos with selenium. the result I want to get is a list of comments. each comment with it's posting date.

right now I can get the comments alone in a list and the comments posting time alone . I tried to run both lists and write ech 'n' element of the list of comments with the 'n'th element of date list but it's not giving me the result I want. Here's my code:

```
#get comments
comment_div=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="contents"]')
comments=comment_div.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="content-text"]')**

#get date
times=comment_div.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[contains(@class,"yt-simple- 
endpoint style-scope yt-formatted-string")]')

#print result
for i in range(len(times)):
    print(comments[i].text + ' , ' + times[i].text)
```

Comment: What result are you seeing?

Comment: And what are the expected results?

Comment: many comments doesnt have their posting date..I need to get each comment with it's posting date at once

Comment: And does the web page contains a posting date for every comment?  What is the len of times and what is the len of comments?

Comment: yes every youtube comment have an element indicating how much time it's been since it was posted  ( exemple : "2 years ago" )

Comment: So your code (and the code I have posted as an answer) should work. Add debug code like `print(len(comments))  print(len(times))`

Answer (score 1):

Under the assumption that each comment comes with a posting time you can use [zip](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) in order to merge the two lists.

```
# Assuming we two lists with the same length
comments = [ "comment1", "comment2", "comment3", "comment4" ] 
post_times = [ "t1","t2","t3","t4" ] 
comments_ex = zip(comments,post_times) 
for comment in comments_ex:
  print(comment)
```

Output

```
('comment1', 't1')
('comment2', 't2')
('comment3', 't3')
('comment4', 't4')
```

Comment: and `list(zip(comments,post_times))` to get as a list

Comment: that did help.thanks .although I came to realize that the my code also works...the problem was and still that am not getting the dates of all the comments for some reason

Comment: Ok. This is a different issue. Try to add the div elements to the post so it will be easier to understand why you have a mismatch.